# EclipseLink how to use two @OneToMany and @ManyToOne to replace @ManyToMany

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am new in eclipselink and trying to add extra columns in manyTomany association table.

so i decide to use  two @OneToMany and @ManyToOne to replace @ManyToMany relationship.

i have tried the hibernate way in the following link, but it does't work.
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Is there anyone know how to build this in eclispelink?

Thanks

-------------------------just follow the link above and paste test code --------------

SideA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SideA")
    public class SideA {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long  id;

    private List<ABAssociation> association = new ArrayList<ABAssociation>();


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.sideA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ABAssociation> getAssociation() {
          return this.association;
    }

    public void setAssociation(List<ABAssociation> association) {
    this.association = association;
    }

}
```

SideB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SideB")
public class SideB {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long  id;


    private List<ABAssociation> association = new ArrayList<ABAssociation>();


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.sideB", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ABAssociation> getAssociation() {
        return this.association;
    }

    public void setAssociation(List<ABAssociation> association) {
        this.association = association;
    }

}
```

Associtation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABAssociation")
@AssociationOverrides({
   @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.sideA", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SIDEA_ID")),
   @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.sideB", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SIDEB_ID")) })
public class ABAssociation {
   private ABAssociationPK pk = new ABAssociationPK();
   @EmbeddedId
   public ABAssociationPK getPk() {
        return pk;
   }
   public void setPk(ABAssociationPK pk) {
       this.pk = pk;
   }
   @Transient
   public SideA getSideA() {
       return getPk().getSideA();
   }
   public void setSideA(SideA sideA) {
       getPk().setSideA(sideA);
   }
   @Transient
   public SideB getSideB() {
       return getPk().getSideB();
   }
   public void setSideB(SideB sideB) {
       getPk().setSideB(sideB);
   } 
   private String extracolumn;
}
```

ABAssociationPK:

```
@Embeddable
public class ABAssociationPK implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3797694126054440157L;

    private SideA sideA;
    private SideB sideB;
    public ABAssociationPK(){}

    @ManyToOne
    public SideA getSideA() {
        return sideA;
    }

    public void setSideA(SideA sideA) {
        this.sideA = sideA;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public SideB getSideB() {
        return sideB;
    }

    public void setSideB(SideB sideB) {
        this.sideB = sideB;
    }

}
```

the exception is :`Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [testPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7298] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The mapping [sideA] from the embedded ID class [class com.fuhu.nabisync.resource.model.entity.ABAssociationPK] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [pk] from the source [class com.fuhu.nabisync.resource.model.entity.ABAssociation]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.`

Comment: What doesn't work? Code? Exception?

Comment: its hibernate style... which cannot apply to eclipselink :  for example "@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.category") "  the pk is  the @embededid for association table. but this doesnt work in eclipselink.

Comment: What doesn't work? Code? Exception? Why do you use an embedded ID in your "Join" entity in the first place?

Comment: Hi Nizet, i have update the test code and exception messing , using the method provide by the link:http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: You are also mixing annotation access types by putting them on fields and properties.  This will cause some to be ignored.  Make sure that you place all annotation on fields or properties, not on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is pretty clear:

> An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification can
>   only contain basic mappings.

So, you can't have a ManyToOne association inside the ABAssociationPK class.

The standard JPA way of doing this is to use the [`@MapsId` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html). The javadoc provides a helpful example. In your particular situation, the `ABAssociationPK` class should contain two fields of type `long`: `aId` and `bId`, mapped as basic columns.

The `Association` entity should contain the associations, and use the `@MapsId` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("aId")
public SideA getSideA() {
    return sideA;
}

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("bId")
public SideB getSideB() {
    return sideB;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i change the test code with your instruction, eclipselink generate 5 tables :ABASSOCIATION,   SIDEA,  SIDEA_ABASSOCIATION,  SIDEB , SIDEB _ABASSOCIATION . is that normal? how can i remove SIDEA_ABASSOCIATION and SIDEB _ABASSOCIATION .  Thanks

Comment: I haven't specified the mapping of the ManyToOne associations. Map them as you want, as long as the MapsId annotation is there.

Comment: You are getting SIDEA_ABASSOCIATION and SIDEB _ABASSOCIATION because the SideA->AbAssocation mappings must be missing the mappedby specification.  Without that or other mapping specifications, a OneToMany will default to using a join table just like a ManyToMany, and those are the default table names.